# Need to create a large.xls spreadsheet with Apache Poi with limited heap memory usage

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to extract data from an internal database and store in an .xls spreadsheet. I already have this working using Apache Poi, I retrieve my data one row at a time and add it as a row to the newly created spreadsheet and after writing the last row I save the workbook using a fileoutputstream.

This is working fine, the trouble is sometimes the spreadsheet to be created can be as large as 200,000 rows and each row consists of 100 columns so it is my understanding that as I create my workbook the whole thing is stored in heap memory until I save this to file, hence there is not enough heap memory to do this for very large spreadsheets.

So what I essentially want to do is something like:

```
Create Spreadsheet and save to file.
For each row
    Open Spreadsheet File
    Add Row
    Save to File
```

So that we do not use an ever increasing amount of heap memory.

I can see how to reopen the Workbook, and add a new row in memory but Im not clear how to resave the modified workbook, nor am I clear is whether as the worksheet gets larger that it will read in all the data anyway as the file is opened making my idea pointless.

I can also see some poi apis but they don't seem to be for the actual .xls format which is what I want to use for maximum compatability.

What is the correct way to write a large number of rows to .xls spreadsheet using a limited amount of memory. Essentially analogous to appending data to a text file.

Comment: Have you tried using [SXSSF](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) (Apache POI's XSSF streaming extension)? It seems tailor-made for your use case.

Comment: klehelley it seems that is only for the .xlsx format, Im not clear how well that format is supported, I want the spreadsheet I create to be easily assessible to as many different devices as possible

Comment: @klehelly ive converted to SXSSF and apart form an issue with sheet.autoSizeColumn(n) everything works and the memory issued is solved. It is also clear there isn't currently a way to use a small memory footprint when writing to .xls files with poi so Im going to stick with .xlsx and hope its is well supported enough. I suppose if there is an issue may be a method to simply convert .xlsx to .xls after created.

Comment: I seem to remember, that Excel (not sure if this applies to the other programs you are targeting) is happy when you have a CSV file with `.xls` extension. So if you don't need certain formatting, this might be an option.

Comment: @RainerSchwarze thanks but that wouldnt work for me, the file is actually multiple sheets because having all 100 columns on one sheet made it difficult to use, so instead I have grouped columns and split over 5 sheets. Csv would not provide the multiple sheet option.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten about SXSSF being limited to XLSX. I haven't used Apache POI for a while now, and only took a couple of minutes to check and post (hence why I limited myself to a comment). Since XLSX is a 10 year old format now, I suppose it is pretty safe to use, however be sure to check that this is something the users of your application can work with. It'd be a shame if by solving your problem this way you created a bigger organisational issue. ^_^;;

Comment: I have moved to SXSSF and XLSX as it is the only way I could find to do in  a memory efficient manner